# Android facebook easy share without api hassle?

Tags: android, facebook, share

Not that I am lazy to setup the api code to have it working, but asking my clients to go through all the hassles to setup a facebook app, a heroku web site, ssh, git, etc etc would really piss them off.

What I really want to do is to let the users of my clients' apps to share some pre-generated text, a link and a picture wrapped together like a little Facebook timeline story. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you are limiting this to facebook? Android has the share intent that can do all of the above with any social network or service the user cares to use...

Comment: because most of my clients want this feature>_< The share intent way was already implemented.

Comment: I would say this is really more an issue of client education. If you don't want to set up a full on facebook app, use the sdk and have the user login to your app, and authorise your app to make wall posts, there is nothing left to do about it...